# libgdx - как реализовать движение тела по параболе

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Здравствуйте, пишу игру на libgdx. Пока я вместо картинок сделал квадраты. Чем дольше нажимаешь на квадрат - тем сильнее должно вылетать тело из его центра и двигаться по параболе.

**Что мы имеем**

- Угол постоянно равен 45°
- Скорость зависит от длительности нажатия (максимум 20 px/сек)
- Дальность полёта

  L = u² * sin 90 / 9.81

или

```
L = u²/9.81
```

**Вопрос 1**

Как можно перевести пиксели в метры? Ведь ускорение свободного падения `9.81 м/с`, а скорость тела на экране выражена в пикселях за секунду.

**Вопрос 2**

Как можно сделать полёт параболой? Допустим скорость 10px/сек. Получается, мне нужно снижать какую-то скорость за какое-то время. Когда она станет равна нулю, тело достигнет максимальной высоты. Ну дальше понятно, продолжать снижать скорость и тело будет снижаться. **Так вот**, какое же такое время то брать? Я ломаю мозг второй день и ничего в голову не лезет. Как же снижать скорость и время правильно? Не говоря уже о том, как это прописать в коде. Объясните, я новичок в геймдеве и это первое задание сводит меня с ума. Чего так сложно-то? Как это реализовать? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто абстрагируйтесь от параболы и посмотрите, как должно лететь тело.
Посмотрите на его вектора.

Есть тело. Есть вектор скорости. Есть вектор ускорения свободного падения. Добавим небольшое сопротивление воздуха, которое будет уменьшать длину вектора скорости на небольшую величину, если скрость тела не равна 0.

Угол между вектором скорости и вектором ускорения свободного падения равен 135 градусов, если мы стреляем вверх под углом в 45 градусов к горизонту.
Как эти векторы будут влиять друг на друга? Векторная алгебра и правило параллелограмма нам помогут.

Как нам посчитать, где должен быть снаряд в текущий момент времени? Мы должны узнать, где он был единицу времени назад (1 секунду, например), дальше мы должны принять некоторое количество пикселей за 1 метр, если мы хотим работать со стандартными единицами измерения.

Пусть масштаб нашей модели такой, что 1 пиксель = 1 метру.

Пусть начальное ускорение нашего снаряда равно 50 м/с^2 и коэффициент гашения скорости пусть будет -0.5 м/с. Ускорение свободного падения оставим 9.8 м/с^2.

Пусть у нас будут экранные координаты x,y:

0,0 - 500,0
0,500 - 500,500

т.е. ось Х идёт вправо, а ось У - вниз.

Стреляем из точки 0,500 вправо (в сторону 500,0, если у нас не было бы других сил).

У нас две компоненты вектора скорости: по Х и по У. Назовём их Vx и Vy.
V - это вектор скорости нашего снаряда. g - вектор ускорения свободного падения. k - коэффициент гашения скорости за счёт трения о среду. Будем считать его для простоты константой для компонент Vx и Vy, для простоты.
a - угол между землёй и линией запуска снаряда.

Начальная точка движения x=0,y=500.
Начальное состояние двух компонент скорости:

Vx = V * cos(a);

Vx = V * sin(a);

Здорово, что угол равен 45 градусам.

Vx = 70,71 м/с.
Vy = 70,71 м/с.

Дальше забываем о синусах, косинусах.

Теперь, для нашего снаряда мы каждую секунду можем знать его характеристики.

Через секунду после выстрела наш снаряд будет находиться в координатах:

x1 = x + Vx;
y1 = y - Vy; (летим против оси У, напомню)

А через две секунды:

x2 = x1 + (Vx - k);
y2 = y1 - (Vy - g*1 - k); // тут *1 можно опустить.

Т.е. каждое новое значение координат снаряда вычисляем из предыдущего.

```
x = x + (Vx - k);
y = y - (Vy - g - k);
```

Дальше, нам поможет картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Но я все равно не пойму. Как из этого всего получится парабола, то?

Comment: Именно момент, когда тело теряет скорость и начинает падать. Не понимаю как(((

Comment: Я думаю, тут хорошее объяснение: http://www.eduspb.com/node/1669
Кратко: обе координаты зависят от времени. между координатами квадратичная зависимость получается в итоге.

Comment: Но это только для угла = 45° ?

Comment: Для других углов - поросто другие Vx и Vy начальные будут. Формулы те же.

Comment: Спасибо. Попытаюсь сделать.